# Capybara: how to check the TEXT value of an element with xpath and css?

Tags: capybara

Trying to make this test to fail without success.

I've got this HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="/url">TV</a>
```

And then I was trying to identify the text of the A element and make it fail for now.

I've used all the following expressions with Xpath but all of them keep passing even though I'm using a different text for the comparison :S

```
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='navigation']//a", :content => 'Radio')
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='navigation']//a", :text => 'Radio')
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='navigation']//a[contains(string(),'Radio')]")
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='navigation']//a[contains(text(),'Radio')]")
page.should have_xpath("//div[@id='navigation']//a[contains(.,'Radio')]")
```

Any idea how I could identify the text of an specific HTML element with capybara?
and... is it possible to achieve the same with CSS?

Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that there was another element with the text 'Radio' in the 'navigation' DIV, so that was causing the test to fail.

For future reference, identifying the 1st element explicitly behaved as expected and fails the test:

```
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should == 'Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should eq('Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should match('Radio')
page.first('div#navigation a').text.should be('Radio')
```

Answer (score 23):

As of RSpec 2.11 (July 2012), the preferred way is to use the `expect` syntax:

```
expect(page).to have_css("#navigation a", text: "Radio")
```

You can [configure RSpec](http://betterspecs.org/#expect) to only accept this new syntax to keep your codebase consistent.

Comment: Haha, unhandled exception. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Using  `have_selector`

`expect(page).to have_selector("#navigation a", text: "Radio")`

Answer (score 0):

It'll help you:

> page.should have_css('div#navigation a', :text == 'Radio')

try this.

Comment: I think there's a typo. `:text == 'Radio'` should be `:text => 'Radio'`

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here so I can find it next time I run into this. :P

My html looks like this:

```
<a href="https://foo.com" id="foo-link">@foo</a>
```

I want to find the text and url value and assert that they are correct. Using Capybary 2.16, Rails 5.1 and minitest here's how I did that:

```
assert_selector 'a#foo-link[href="https://foo.com"]', text: '@foo'
```

If the ID, text or href value change the test will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//*[@href='']", text: 'TV')
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by adding an explaination and how it differs/is better than the other existing answers

Comment: My thought was that it is more strict to use xpath blend with text in order to select and check elements because probably you'll have multiple elements with the same class. There is also no answer that uses xpath above.